# How to send multiple information trought QTcpSocket at the same time?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, sockets, qtcpsocket

im doing a small client/server reservation app and im stuck on how i can send the information of the classes, Actually i have 3 classes and im sending the information like this:

```
VentanaPrincipalS::VentanaPrincipalS(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::VentanaPrincipalS)
{
  //..Methods..//
  connect(conexion,SIGNAL(nuevaConexion(QTcpSocket*)), this, SLOT(enviarDataCliente(QTcpSocket*)));
  connect(conexion,SIGNAL(nuevaConexion(QTcpSocket*)), this, SLOT(enviarDataVuelo(QTcpSocket*)));
  connect(conexion,SIGNAL(nuevaConexion(QTcpSocket*)), this, SLOT(enviarDataReservacion(QTcpSocket*)));
   //..Methods..//
}
void VentanaPrincipalS::enviarDataVuelo(QTcpSocket *sock)
{
  QByteArray buffer;
  QDataStream out(&buffer, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
  out << 1;
  for(int i = 0; i < empresa.cantidadVuelos(); i++){
      out << empresa.getVuelos().at(i)->getDestino() << empresa.getVuelos().at(i)->getIdVuelo() << empresa.getVuelos().at(i)->getPartida();
  }
  if(sock->isValid())
  {
    sock->write(buffer);
  }

}
//2 More methods just like this, switching the out first number
to know which class is...//
```

In the client side i receive like this:

```
in>> caracterControl;
    switch(caracterControl){
    case 1:{
        while(!in.atEnd()){
            QString destino;
            QString id;
            QDate fecha;
            in >> destino >> id >> fecha;
            qDebug()<< destino +" "+ id + " " + fecha.toString();
            MVuelo vuelop(id, destino, fecha);
            listaVuelos.append(id);
            vuelosRecibidos.push_back(vuelop);
        }
     }
     case 2:{
        while(!in.atEnd()){
            QString cedula;
            QString correo;
            QString nombre;
            QString telf;
            in >> cedula >> correo >> nombre >> telf;
            MCliente cliente(nombre, cedula, telf, correo);
            qDebug()<< "Cliente: " + cedula;
        }
     }
    case 3:{
       while(!in.atEnd()){
           QString reserva;
           QString vuelo;
           in >> reserva >> vuelo;
           qDebug()<< "Reserva: " + reserva;
       }
    }

}
```

1, 2 or 3 that depends on the class.

The Problems is that the information is incomplete and is just like the socket
crashes because another method is writing on him, is there a way to receive all
the information in order or a way to tell the server that the socket finish the read?

Please help me ;(...

PD: Yes the server and the socket connects successfully IM SURE OF THAT :)

NOTE: I have a QList with 3 clientes (21727090, 20350202 and 123), and im receiving this trough qDebug()

2

"Cliente: 21727090"

"Cliente: 20350202"

"Cliente: 123"

"Cliente: "

"Cliente: "

"Cliente: "

Comment: What makes you think you can send various data in a TCP socket at the same time ? TCP is stream-based, everything happens sequentially.

Comment: Hmm, this adios-amigos language makes it more difficult to understand than it could be.

Comment: What you recommend SirDarius?

Comment: Is this still unresolved one year later??

Answer (score 0):

> The Problems is that the information is incomplete and is just like the socket crashes because another method is writing on him, is there a way to receive all the information in order or a way to tell the server that the socket finish the read?

The quickest workaround is to put a blocking (i.e. sync) wait in there after the write as follows:

```
if (sock->isValid())
{
    sock->write(buffer);
    if (!sock->waitForBytesWritten(5000))
        qDebug() << QString("Operation timed out or an error occurred for sock, error: %1).arg(sock->errorString());
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work. There is a way to pass all the atributtes of the classes when the socket connects to the server?

Comment: When im try to receive the information on the client side, the system just gets the "clientes" and "vuelos", "reservacion" doesnt show up anywhere. I think that happens because when the socket connnect all the information of the classes is written and sended trought the socket

Comment: @user3050498: have you figured out the nitty-gritty details?